# Optimizing code: is better to use "MyClass = instance;" or create a pointer to it? which is more fast/use less memory?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm new at microcontroller programming, but I know that the less memory I use, the better (obviously, the microcontroller doesn't have much RAM)

so, I want to know the best way to make a new instance of some class (the faster way/the way that use less memory)

I tried using both ways:

Generic Class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
    //generic constructor
    }
};
```

now, which are the best way to declare a new instance of `MyClass`?

this:

```
MyClass my_class_instance;
```

or this:

```
MyClass *my_class_instance_ptr = new MyClass;
```

Like, which one use less memory/is faster?

**edit**: by "less memory/is faster" I expected some answer like "this is more faster but use more memory" or something like this, I know that in programming sometimes we need to "sacrifice" some memory to have more processing speed

Comment: `MyClass my_class_instance;` is faster and needs less memory. `MyClass my_class_instance;` allocates the instance on the stack. `MyClass *my_class_instance_ptr = new MyClass;` allocates a pointer on the stack and the instance on the heap.

Comment: In addition, avoid naked `new`s in your code. Use smart pointers when you really need dynamic allocation.

Comment: *"the faster way/the way that use less memory"* -- please pick one. Sometimes these goals are compatible, but it is not uncommon that speed can be obtained at the cost of space and vice versa.

Comment: Just to be clear: you are wondering which of the following requires less space: 1) create an object of your class, or 2) create an object of your class plus a pointer to that object? No consideration of how the object will be used (which could change the answer), just the space required for construction?

Comment: The other downside of `MyClass *my_class_instance_ptr = new MyClass` is that it is necessary to later do an explicit `delete my_class_instance_ptr` to avoid a memory leak.  That involves additional code, which also often has an impact on memory usage (e.g. by the process).    More significantly, however, is that you are asking the wrong question.   Dynamic memory allocation, in itself, has nothing to do with optimising memory usage.   It is related to how the lifetime of the object needs to be managed (e.g. does the object need to exist outside the scope where it is created).

Comment: In microcontroller programming dynamic memory allocation might not even be avaliable at all (after all, if you have 1KB pf memory, reserving part of it for some memory bookkeeping you might not even need is a huge waste).

Comment: There is no right answer to your question.  A MyClass object will always take the same amount of memory to store.  What is more important for embedded device is _where_ the object is stored, i.e.: in global memory, on the stack, in heap memory (if available), or, more rarely, in memory that's specific to the processor, or to your hardware design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question stems from not knowing the difference between `stack` and `heap`. Please use these keywords to do some research.

Basically, allocating on stack using `MyClass my_class_instance;` is the fastest way.

Arduino does not have an external memory, so technically speaking, heap and stack memory is identical. However, allocating on heap requires some background work, such as finding the next free memory area of the right size.

A very general guideline is to avoid heap allocation on small embedded systems.

Comment: The notion of stack and heap memory aren't even relevant in standard C++. They are relevant to particular implementations (particular platforms and toolchains that target those platforms). Historically, particular platforms had segmented memory in which stack and heap used physically distinct circuits and physical memory, and stack consisted of a small amount of fast memory and heap a (relatively) larger amount of slower memory. In modern platforms, the distinction is usually moot and - unless writing an optimising compiler or an operating system - programmers worry about it unnecessarily.

Comment: @Peter: The notion of stack and heap are *almost* the same as C++'s automatic and dynamic storage, which are super relevant in standard C++. The distinction between them is not relevant for anything in this question